# i18n via h:link or h:button

Tags: java, jsf

All the tutorials out there implement the i18n through a *h:selectOneMenu* ore other sort of select. Is there a way to implement i18n through h:button at least? I tried assigning the bean method to the *outcome* property but it throws an error. assigning the bean method the the *action* property has no effect at all.

```
<h:button outcome="#{languageController.currentLanguage}" value = "#{appMessage['link.label.language.english']}">
   <f:param name="selectedLanguage" value="en" />
</h:button>

public String changeLanguage(){
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String selectedLocale = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("selectedLanguage");
    this.currentLanguage = selectedLocale;
    facesContext.getViewRoot().setLocale(new Locale(currentLanguage));
    return "welcome";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<h:link>` and `<h:button>` send a GET request, not a POST request. The `outcome` value needs to point to the target view. You need to set the view parameter and do the action in the target view by a `<f:viewParam>` and `<f:event type="preRenderView">`.

```html
<h:button outcome="welcome" value="#{appMessage['link.label.language.english']}">
    <f:param name="selectedLanguage" value="en" />
</h:button>
```

with in `welcome.xhtml` (validation omitted)

```html
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="selectedLanguage" value="#{languageController.currentLanguage}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{languageController.changeLanguage}" />
</f:metadata>
```

and in the bean

```
public void changeLanguage() {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    facesContext.getViewRoot().setLocale(new Locale(currentLanguage));
}
```

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF2 - Processing GET request parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters)

Comment: If you go this route, yes. Alternatively you can get it from the request parameter map so that you only need to put the `<f:event>` (which does by itself not require `<f:metadata>`).

Comment: I find it awkward that I have to access changeLanguage at every page. I guess that this is caused by the _getViewRoot().setLocale()_. Is there a way to make the language change permanent, so that the language settings stay the same at every page?

Comment: Just create a master layout template which you reuse in all template clients.